# strcat function not working with pointers

Tags: c, pointers, strcat

```
int main(int argc , int *argv[]){

char str[7] = "Mobile";
char str2[11] = "Samsung4g";

char *str3 = 0;
str3 = ( char* )(malloc(30));

str3 = "Carrier";

strcat(str3, str);//Problem facing here, dunno why
```

Comment: `str3 = "Carrier";` - just leaked the memory allocated immediately before that line. That isn't how you *copy* strings in C.

Comment: `str3 = "Carrier";` -> `strcpy(str3, "Carrier")`.

Comment: `str3 = "Carrier";` just overwrote the address stored with `str3 = ( char* )(malloc(30));` replacing the address with the address of the *String-Literal* `"Carrier"` resulting in `str3` now pointing to the immutable string-literal and the memory leak because you now have no way to `free()` the memory you allocated (you lost the pointer) There is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: Posting a specific question increases the quality of a post.  A post like this, with no question attracts down votes and closure.  user1421147, consider an edit.

Answer (score 0):

Like what others have mentioned in the comments, the statement:

```
str3 = "Carrier";
```

overwrites the value of str3 with the address of the string literal "Carrier" causing the address returned by malloc() to be lost.

Using str3 then in strcat() as a first argument attempts to modify a string literal which results in undefined behaviour.

Use strcpy() or equivalent functions to copy strings in C.